# MVC help link Url.Action no longer resolves

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In one of my views I have a help link which displays a jquery ui dialog describing what the field is for.

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OptionalFields", "Home"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ConfigID)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CampaignName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CampaignName) <a href="#" class="helplinkcampaign">help</a>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LeadStatus)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeadStatus) <a href="#" class="helplinkstatus">help</a>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserOwnerName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserOwnerName) <a href="#" class="helplinkowner">help</a>
    <p><input type="submit" id="optionalfields" value="Save" /></p>
}
```

I have a jquery event handler for each class in the link tags above. Example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".helplinkcampaign", function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Campaign", "Home")';
    $("#divPopup").dialog('option', 'title', 'Campaign Name Help');
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $("#divPopup").html(data);
        $("#divPopup").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

As you can see, I resolve the URL to a controller actionresult and download the content of that view, and display the content in a jquery ui dialog.

This page is a work in progress, but this was working as of yesterday and today has stopped. The error I am getting is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

And the link beside that in the console is

```
http://localhost:12345/Home/@Url.Action(%22Campaign%22,%20%22Home%22)
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:12345/Home/Campaign
```

I know I could manually set the url variable to campaign in this case but I prefer to have MVC resolve it.

Is there any reason why this has stopped resolving?

Answer (score 3):

As **@Y.Tceretian** pointed, possibilty is you moved js code to a seperate js file, so razor code will not be executed if it is not in the view but in a js file.

What you could do is that, you can use data attribute to set the url and then read it in the click event which would be something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CampaignName) 
<a href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Campaign", "Home")" class="helplinkcampaign" >help</a>
```

and thenin your jquery click event handler read the attribute value:

```
$(document).on("click", ".helplinkcampaign", function () {
    var url = $(this).data("url"); // note this
    $("#divPopup").dialog('option', 'title', 'Campaign Name Help');
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $("#divPopup").html(data);
        $("#divPopup").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you moved Javascript piece to separate file that is not put through Razor engine. 
As a workaround, you can resolve url in View and put to some hidden field and then read that fields in Javascript code.